# BC Filler is not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am figuring out the buildcraft filler. Clearing a region works but i cannot get the program to build anything. I am using bricks(336) for the patters filling all the 9 slots. I also have plenty of resources to fill me region. The region is connected to the filler and is colored black/yellow.

Maybe it is not having enough power, i do not understand all the power EU, MJ, etc and converting it. But i hooked up 3 generators to 2 batboxes and linked the 3 electric engines with gold insulated cable. Like i said the filler is clearing the area but not filling it, maybe it does not have enough power?

Comment: Bricks (336) as in individual brick items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filler uses brick *blocks* in the pattern slot, not individual bricks. You should have sufficient power, but the filler doesn't recognize the pattern. The pattern should look like this:

[image: Fill pattern]

Comment: Ok strange since the FTB is refering to bricks with ID 336 and not brick blocks ID 45.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. It has always been brick blocks as far as I remember.